# How to automatically recognise timezone when converting from a datetime saved as character to POSIXct in R?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I'm trying to save a POSIXct datetime as a string with timezone, then convert it back to the original POSIXct datetime with the correct timezone. In the back-conversion, I'm wanting the timezone to be recognised from the string rather than having to specify it manually.

Seems straightforward but I haven't been able to work out a way to do this: I seem to have to either manually specify the timezone (see top example below) or the back-conversion fails (see bottom example).

Any advice much appreciated.

```
# This works, but I'm manually specifying the timezone on the third line. I want to do this automatically.
dt = as.POSIXct('2021-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'Pacific/Auckland') #"2021-01-01 NZDT"
char = format(dt, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS%z') #20210101T000000+1300 (+1300 = NZDT)
as.POSIXct(char, format = '%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS', tz = 'Pacific/Auckland') #2021-01-01 NZDT. Note manually specifying timezone, which I dont want to do.

# Now trying to automatically specify timezone via '%Z' on the third line. This returns NA.  
dt = as.POSIXct('2021-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'Pacific/Auckland')
char = format(dt, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS%z') #"20210101T000000+1300"
as.POSIXct(char, format = '%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS%z') #NA. Note I'm trying to automatically specify timezone via '%Z'
```

Comment: Heyy note that for the time zone only from -1200 to +1200 are supported even though  the claim is that it supports upto +1400

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that -- thanks!

Comment: Yes, this works for my timezone which is GMT +8 but doesn't work for GMT +13.

Comment: What if you force the original timezone into your `char` string? Is that okay? E.g. `char <- format(dt, paste("%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS", attr(dt, "tzone")) )`. Then you can get it back with something like `as.POSIXct(sub("\\s.+$", "", char), format="%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS", tz=sub("^.+\\s", "", char[1]))`

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, that's a workable solution! If you want to post as an answer I'll accept

Comment: @jruf003 - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you force the original timezone into your `char` string? E.g.:

```
dt <- as.POSIXct('2021-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'Pacific/Auckland')
dt
#[1] "2021-01-01 NZDT"

char <- format(dt, paste("%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS", attr(dt, "tzone")) )
char
#[1] "20210101T000000 Pacific/Auckland"
```

Then you can get it back by extracting the datetime part and the timezone part by separating at the first space:

```
as.POSIXct(
  sub("\\s.+$", "", char),
  format = "%Y%m%dT%H%M%OS",
  tz     = sub("^.+\\s", "", char[1])
)
#[1] "2021-01-01 NZDT"
```